# How to request MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_CAMERA permission on android 14 and above

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions

I need to disable device camera from app which is working completely fine in devices <= android 13. But android 14 is telling me that i need MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_CAMERA permission. When I request that permission, it is automatically getting denied. Any one knows how to request this permission?

I need to be able to disable camera in android 14 and above also

Comment: Did you also request [`MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_ACROSS_USERS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_ACROSS_USERS)? [The documentation for `MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_CAMERA`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_CAMERA) is confusing, but it feels like you might need both permissions. Then again, both are `internal|role`, rather than `dangerous`, so you might not be able to request them normally.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried requesting both permissions,but its not working.both are automatically getting denied

Comment: Given that their `permissionLevel` is `internal|role`, that is not shocking. You will need to figure out what role your app needs to hold to be able to have those permissions.